# How to connect armature to mesh?

Tags: modeling, rigging, unity

I created a simple armature, parented all the bones properly, named them and made sure they import to Unity perfectly. The armature seems to be working great. I also have a collection of Meshes, under one object, a humanoid. It's basically just a 3D model with hair, teeth, a dress, etc.

Here's an image:

[image]

I am trying to parent them together, with automatic weights (And I tried all the other options as well). They do parent in the hierarchy but other than that, they're not connected in any way. Moving the bones doesn't move any parts of the model. What am I doing wrong?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9hNLLWHRcw

Looking at this tutorial I'm doing exactly what the person does at 6:07, but in my case the character doesn't move.

Comment: Could you share your blend file?

Comment: Are you selecting the Armature second?

Answer (score -1):

As you are performing the parenting, look at the top of your window, towards the middle. I am willing to bet that you will see an error message of some kind when you do so. The proper solution to your problem almost definitely depends upon what that message says. If it happens to be the trusty Bone Weight error, good luck... I have been trying to solve that particular issue through DAYS of research, but perhaps you will have better luck.